# Appending an image to a div, but the image is called null

Tags: javascript, html

If I change the `document.body.appendChild(tImg) to document.div.appendChild(tImg)`, I get an error saying that I cant appendChild of null. the function happens inside an initialize.

```
function placeFighter(t, imageFile)
    {
        tImg = document.createElement("img");
        tImg.src = imageFile;
        tImg.tangible = t;
        playerImg.push(tImg);
        document.body.appendChild(tImg);
    }
```

Comment: `document` object has [`body`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/body) property but does not have `div` property.

Comment: if you want to append the element to some div you have to use any of the various dom methods to get it first: querySelector/All, getElementByid, getElementsByName, getElementsByTagName etc

Comment: PM 77-1, thx for reminding me lol. I just remembered(No sarcasm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add an id to your div and change the code to this.

```
function placeFighter(t, imageFile){
    var tImg = document.createElement("img");
    tImg.src = imageFile;
    tImg.tangible = t;
    playerImg.push(tImg);
    document.getElementById('MyDiv').appendChild(tImg);
}
```